# How to fix the "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'find'" error when plotting with the x-axis as bins?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, binning

I have a dataframe with 2 columns `x` and `y` that contains 10 bins of a column of some other dataframe and their respective values. I am trying to plot the `x`s against the `y`s, but I get the error:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y'])

df['x'] = ['19.0-23.0', '24.0-28.0', '29.0-33.0', '34.0-38.0', '39.0-43.0', '44.0-48.0', '49.0-53.0', '54.0-58.0', '59.0-63.0', '64.0-68.0']
df['y'] = ['0.065217', '0.039548', '0.06015', '0.054945', '0.085366', '0.071429', '0.137931', '0.129032', '0.190476', '0']

plt.plot([str(i) for i in df['x']], df['y']) 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-001ebdb8bf81> in <module>()
      7 df['y'] = ['0.065217', '0.039548', '0.06015', '0.054945', '0.085366', '0.071429', '0.137931', '0.129032', '0.190476', '0']
      8 
----> 9 plt.plot([str(i) for i in df['x']], df['y'])

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in plot(*args, **kwargs)
   3315                       mplDeprecation)
   3316     try:
-> 3317         ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
   3318     finally:
   3319         ax._hold = washold

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1896                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1897                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1898             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1899         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1900         if pre_doc is None:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in plot(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1404         kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, _alias_map)
   1405 
-> 1406         for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
   1407             self.add_line(line)
   1408             lines.append(line)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _grab_next_args(self, *args, **kwargs)
    405                 return
    406             if len(remaining) <= 3:
--> 407                 for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
    408                     yield seg
    409                 return

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    355         ret = []
    356         if len(tup) > 1 and is_string_like(tup[-1]):
--> 357             linestyle, marker, color = _process_plot_format(tup[-1])
    358             tup = tup[:-1]
    359         elif len(tup) == 3:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _process_plot_format(fmt)
     92     # handle the multi char special cases and strip them from the
     93     # string
---> 94     if fmt.find('--') >= 0:
     95         linestyle = '--'
     96         fmt = fmt.replace('--', '')

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   4374             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   4375                 return self[name]
-> 4376             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   4377 
   4378     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'find'
```

This error is arising because it wants to convert the `df[x]` values into floats. But why? They are strings, and they should be plotted as such. I have been doing these plots for other datasets, and I've gotten this error only now on this particular dataset. But I've not been able to determine what exactly in this dataset is different that's causing this error.

For now, I am fixing it by plotting the `y`s against a default x-axis, and then labelling the x-ticks manually:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y'])

df['x'] = ['19.0-23.0', '24.0-28.0', '29.0-33.0', '34.0-38.0', '39.0-43.0', '44.0-48.0', '49.0-53.0', '54.0-58.0', '59.0-63.0', '64.0-68.0']
df['y'] = ['0.065217', '0.039548', '0.06015', '0.054945', '0.085366', '0.071429', '0.137931', '0.129032', '0.190476', '0']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(df['y'])
labels = ['19.0-23.0', '24.0-28.0', '29.0-33.0', '34.0-38.0', '39.0-43.0', '44.0-48.0', '49.0-53.0', '54.0-58.0', '59.0-63.0', '64.0-68.0']
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
plt.show()
```

But this is a tedious fix, if not a convoluted one, and this issue shouldn't even occur in the first place, like it didn't in my other datasets. So, why is this occuring and how do I fix it properly?

Comment: Find the string which cannot be converted to a float and print it?

Comment: Its the `df[x]` values, obviously, if you look at them. What I don't get is, why I never got this error before on other datasets where I did the exact same thing, and am only getting it now? Why does it want to convert the bins to floats? They are strings, and it should just plot them as they are, just like it did on my other datasets.

Comment: `plt.plot([str(i) for i in df.x], df.y) ` works just fine for me.

Comment: The code from the question works fine for me, which means it could well be a matter of updating matplotlib and pandas.

Comment: Hmmm. But this works on a different dataset. I checked just now again. Why might that be?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Lol, after restarting the iPython kernel, its now working fine. What a dumb waste of time!